# OpenVPN redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp not working on 3G

Tags: vpn, openvpn

## Edit

I followed @begueradj advice in comments and posted the question on ServerFault : https://serverfault.com/questions/709340/openvpn-redirect-gateway-not-working-on-3g-cellular

---

## Original Question

I have trouble setting up an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 14.04.
I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) from Digital Ocean step by step and it works perfectly for all WiFi devices such as my laptops and desktop either on Linux (Ubuntu fork), OS X 10.11 or Windows 7 or 10. It also works on my iPhone (iOS 9 beta) when connecting on WiFi.

However, when I want to use my 3G connection with Free Mobile (French carrier), it doesn't work.

I tried to comment out the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` on the server. I can now browse websites, but my public IP is no more the one of the VPN.

The only clue I could have found seems to be [here (FR)](http://linuxfr.org/forums/linux-android/posts/configuration-openvpn-en-udp-sur-connexion-freemobile). The guy explains that setting the `mssfix 1300` instruction works on his client (he has an Android phone), but it doesn't work for me.

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome. This is not the right place for such questions. May be you can ask [here](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, welcome to [security.se]. Please do not crosspost on other SE sites, instead flag the question to be migrated over. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this existed. In fact I flagged it to be closed or deleted after reposting it. Thank you for pointing that to me!